# Maintaining oath callback URLs

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js, loopbackjs, passport-github2

I'm developing a Loopback-based NodeJS app that uses GitHub Passport auth. For my development, I use localhost in my `callbackURL` setting in `providers.json`, but I have to change it to the published URL every time I deploy. At the same time, I have to change the same setting on GitHub.

How do you handle such scenarios? Is it possible to put a setting in `providers.json`? Is it possible to use two applications on GitHub and switch between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are loading the `providers.json` file in your `server.js` like in documentation: (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Configuring-providers.json.html)

```
var config = {};
try {
  config = require('../providers.json');
} catch (err) {
  console.trace(err);
  process.exit(1); // fatal
}
```

So you can create two separate `providers.json` files (e.g. providers.dev.json providers.prod.json) and load a proper one according to e.g. NODE_ENV environment variable